# How do i do running totals from second column

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, window-functions, analytic-functions

I have a data set like below,

```
Lot Size    Reported QTY    Qty Balance
150          100            
150          100            
150          80             
150          80            
150          5
```

The Qty Balance needs to calculated as follows,

```
Row 1 = Lot Size - Reported Qty (row1) => 150-100 = 50
Row 2 = Reported Qty (row1) - Reported Qty(row2) => 100-100 =0
Row 3 = Reported Qty (row2) - Reported Qty(row3) => 100-80 =20
... till the last row
```

My expected result is

```
Lot Size    Reported QTY    Qty Balance
150          100            50
150          100            0
150          80             20
150          80             0
150          5              75
```

How do I achieve this in a query?

Comment: All great answers.. Thanks guys !! I just chose the answer that worked for me best as the best answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b32d5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE lots ( Lot_Size, Reported_QTY ) AS
          SELECT 150, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 150, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 150,  80 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 150,  80 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 150,   5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Lot_Size,
       Reported_QTY,
       COALESCE( LAG( Reported_QTY ) OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) - Reported_QTY,
                 Lot_Size - Reported_QTY ) AS Qty_Balance
FROM   Lots
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b32d5/1/0)**:

```
| LOT_SIZE | REPORTED_QTY | QTY_BALANCE |
|----------|--------------|-------------|
|      150 |          100 |          50 |
|      150 |          100 |           0 |
|      150 |           80 |          20 |
|      150 |           80 |           0 |
|      150 |            5 |          75 |
```

Comment: You don't need a coalesce - you can do it entirely within the lag function. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `LAG()` analytic function. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#i1327527) for details on the function and the parameters it accepts (for example, I think you're going to need to pass in a default of the lot_size column for when the lag() function returns null.)

Once you've identified the previous row's reported qty value, then you can simply subtract it. You will, of course, need some way of identifying the order of the rows - your sample data doesn't appear to have one, so the database won't be able to determine which row is first and which is last.

Eg.

```
with sample_data (lot_size, reported_qty) as (SELECT 150, 100 FROM DUAL
                                              UNION ALL SELECT 150, 100 FROM DUAL
                                              UNION ALL SELECT 150,  80 FROM DUAL
                                              UNION ALL SELECT 150,  80 FROM DUAL
                                              UNION ALL SELECT 150,   5 FROM DUAL)
select lot_size,
       reported_qty,
       lag(reported_qty, 1, lot_size) over (order by null) - reported_qty diff
from   sample_data;

  LOT_SIZE REPORTED_QTY       DIFF
---------- ------------ ----------
       150          100         50
       150          100          0
       150           80         20
       150           80          0
       150            5         75
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Boneist suggested, you need to use **LAG() OVER()** analytic function.

You just need to do one more task to handle the first row which will be NULL, using **CASE** you could make it work.

**Test case**

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    ( SELECT t.*, lag(reported_qty) OVER(ORDER BY NULL) rn FROM t
  3    )
  4  SELECT lot_size,
  5    reported_qty,
  6    CASE
  7      WHEN rn IS NULL
  8      THEN lot_size     - reported_qty
  9      ELSE rn - reported_qty
 10    END qty_balance
 11  FROM data;

  LOT_SIZE REPORTED_QTY QTY_BALANCE
---------- ------------ -----------
       150          100          50
       150          100           0
       150           80          20
       150           80           0
       150            5          75

SQL>
```

Comment: You don't need a case statement - you can do it entirely within the lag function. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @Boneist Yeah, subtle! `offset` and `default` are the keys. Good point, thanks.

Comment: @Boneist Sorry for misspelling your name... By the way, we could create some good music together when we meet someday. Will show you my guitar and singing skills :-)

Comment: That's ok; I've seen all sorts of variations *{;-) I'm not so sure guitar and trombone would mix terribly well, though!